# Process elements in futures::stream::Stream concurrently with reference to shared tasks

Tags: rust

I am trying to connect to multiple peers and process a series of asynchronous tasks for each peer. Once a task is completed by any peer it should short-circuit the task for all other peers even if the task is in progress.

In the following example I have 3 tasks:

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::rc::Rc;

use futures::stream::StreamExt;
use rand::Rng;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Task {
    id: u32,
}

impl Task {
    fn process<'a>(&'a self, peer: &'a str) -> impl futures::future::Future<Output = ()> + 'a {
        let delay = core::time::Duration::from_secs(rand::thread_rng().gen_range(5..10));
        async move {
            tokio::time::sleep(delay).await;
            println!("{} completed task #{} first", peer, self.id);
        }
    }
}

async fn process_task(task: &Task, done_with_task: &Rc<RefCell<bool>>, notify_task: &Arc<tokio::sync::Notify>, peer: &str) {
    if !*done_with_task.borrow() {
        tokio::select! {
            process = task.process(peer) => {
                done_with_task.replace(true);
                notify_task.notify_waiters();
            }
            cancel = notify_task.notified() => {}
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let peers = vec!["peer A", "peer B", "peer C"];
    let peers = futures::stream::iter(peers);

    let (tx, rx) = tokio::sync::mpsc::channel(100);

    let rx = tokio_stream::wrappers::ReceiverStream::new(rx);
    let rx = peers.chain(rx);

    let tasks = vec![
        Task {id: 1},
        Task {id: 2},
        Task {id: 3},
    ];

    let notify_task_1 = Arc::new(tokio::sync::Notify::new());
    let done_with_task_1 = Rc::new(RefCell::new(false));

    let notify_task_2 = Arc::new(tokio::sync::Notify::new());
    let done_with_task_2 = Rc::new(RefCell::new(false));

    let notify_task_3 = Arc::new(tokio::sync::Notify::new());
    let done_with_task_3 = Rc::new(RefCell::new(false));

    let handle_conn_fut = rx.for_each_concurrent(0, |peer| {
        let mut tasks = tasks.clone().into_iter();

        let notify_task_1 = notify_task_1.clone();
        let notify_task_2 = notify_task_2.clone();
        let notify_task_3 = notify_task_3.clone();

        let done_with_task_1 = done_with_task_1.clone();
        let done_with_task_2 = done_with_task_2.clone();
        let done_with_task_3 = done_with_task_3.clone();

        async move {
            println!("connecting to {}", peer);

            // task #1
            let current_task = tasks.next().unwrap();
            process_task(&current_task, &done_with_task_1, &notify_task_1, peer).await;
            println!("task #{} done for {}", current_task.id, peer);
            
            // task #2
            let current_task = tasks.next().unwrap();
            process_task(&current_task, &done_with_task_2, &notify_task_2, peer).await;
            println!("task #{} done for {}", current_task.id, peer);

            // task #3
            let current_task = tasks.next().unwrap();
            process_task(&current_task, &done_with_task_3, &notify_task_3, peer).await;
            println!("task #{} done for {}", current_task.id, peer);
        }
    });

    let create_new_conn_fut = async move {
        // a new peer connects after 10 seconds
        tokio::time::sleep(core::time::Duration::from_secs(10)).await;
        tx.send("peer D").await.unwrap()
    };

    // awaits both futures in parallell
    futures::future::join(handle_conn_fut, create_new_conn_fut).await;

}
```

output:

```
connecting to peer A
connecting to peer B
connecting to peer C
peer A completed task #1 first
task #1 done for peer A
task #1 done for peer C
task #1 done for peer B
connecting to peer D
task #1 done for peer D
peer B completed task #2 first
task #2 done for peer B
task #2 done for peer D
task #2 done for peer C
task #2 done for peer A
peer B completed task #3 first
task #3 done for peer B
task #3 done for peer A
task #3 done for peer C
task #3 done for peer D
```

The output is correct, but I am trying to find a more idiomatic way to write this, without explicitly needing to handle each task.

I have thought of storing the tasks in a [`futures::stream::FuturesOrdered`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/struct.FuturesOrdered.html), but I am not sure how to go about this.

With abuse of notation, I would like something like this to work in theory:

```rust
let tasks = Rc::new(RefCell::new(tasks)) // ?
let handle_conn_fut = rx.for_each_concurrent(0, |peer| {
    async move {
        println!("connecting to {}", peer);
        while let Some(task) = tasks.borrow().next() {
            tokio::select! {
                complete = tasks.process(peer) => {
                    // mutate tasks
                    tasks.borrow_mut().pop() // ?
                }
                state_change = tasks.is_mutated() => {} // ?
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by storing the current task in a [`tokio::sync::watch::channel`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/watch/fn.channel.html) which makes it possible to await changes to the task with [`has_changed`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/watch/struct.Receiver.html#method.has_changed). The backlog or future tasks needs to stored in mutable memory location that can be moved into different async blocks, so I used `Rc<RefCell<Vec<Task>>>` for this. One could maybe use the `Rc<RefCell<Vec<Task>>>` directly together with `tokio::sync::Notify` instead of a channel, but I had some trouble with borrowing and mutating the `Rc<RefCell<Vec<Task>>>` simultaneously in `process_task`as explained here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#panics-4

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

use futures::stream::StreamExt;
use rand::Rng;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Task {
    id: u32,
}

impl Task {
    fn process<'a>(&'a self, peer: &'a str) -> impl futures::future::Future<Output = ()> + 'a {
        let delay = core::time::Duration::from_secs(rand::thread_rng().gen_range(5..10));
        async move {
            tokio::time::sleep(delay).await;
            println!("{} completed task #{} first", peer, self.id);
        }
    }
}

async fn process_task(task: &Task, peer: &str, task_backlog: &Rc<RefCell<Vec<Task>>>, tx_task: &tokio::sync::watch::Sender<Task>, rx_task: &mut tokio::sync::watch::Receiver<Task>) {
    tokio::select! {
        process = task.process(peer) => {
            let new_task = task_backlog.borrow_mut().pop().unwrap();
            tx_task.send(new_task).unwrap()
        }
        cancel = rx_task.changed() => {}
    }
}


#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let peers = vec!["peer A", "peer B", "peer C"];
    let peers = futures::stream::iter(peers);

    let (tx, rx) = tokio::sync::mpsc::channel(100);

    let rx = tokio_stream::wrappers::ReceiverStream::new(rx);
    let rx = peers.chain(rx);

    let task_backlog = Rc::new(RefCell::new(vec![
        Task {id: 3},
        Task {id: 2},
    ]));

    let (tx_task, rx_task) = tokio::sync::watch::channel(Task { id: 1 });
    let tx_task_ref = &tx_task;

    let handle_conn_fut = rx.for_each_concurrent(0, |peer| {
        let task_backlog = task_backlog.clone();

        let mut rx_task = rx_task.clone();
        let tx_task = tx_task_ref.clone();

        async move {
            println!("connecting to {}", peer);
            loop {
                let current_task = rx_task.borrow_and_update().clone();
                process_task(&current_task, peer, &task_backlog, &tx_task, &mut rx_task).await;
                println!("task #{} done for {}", current_task.id, peer);
            }
        }
    });

    let create_new_conn_fut = async move {
        // a new peer connects after 10 seconds
        tokio::time::sleep(core::time::Duration::from_secs(10)).await;
        tx.send("peer D").await.unwrap()
    };

    // awaits both futures in parallell
    futures::future::join(handle_conn_fut, create_new_conn_fut).await;
}
```